# mysql count hour each day

Tags: mysql, sum

I have a table as follow:

```
id   datestart    dateend       hours
1    2014-07-21   2014-07-25    1.5
2    2014-07-28   2014-07-31    2
```

In MySQL, how do I query if I wish to return sum (hours) for everyday (datestart to dateend) and result like below:

```
id   daterange (datestart - dateend) totalhours(hours)
1    2014-07-21   2014-07-25         7.5
2    2014-07-28   2014-07-31         8
```

as you can see each day is equals to hours.

the below SQL is not really convincing.

```
select id, datediff (end, start) * `hours` as total_hours
from project_staff_assignment
```

it doesn't return the actual hours, it doesnt include or count the start date and end date

Comment: im not really good in sql queries

Comment: I could understand 6 as desired value for `id = 2`, but how in the world did one get 10?

Comment: First row: 4 days 1.5 hours per day: 6 hours, ok. Second row: 3 days 2 hours per day: why 8 hours? I would expect 6 hours.

Comment: 28 to 31 counted as 4 days.. so 4 * 2(hours) = 8

Comment: @Strawberry Apparently, the date ranges are inclusive, which is not totally unusual in the SQL world, as evident from the BETWEEN operator.

Comment: @JosephB I'm guessing you're not up to speed with the various edits.

Comment: select id, SUM(datediff (end, start) + 2) * `hours` as total_hours
from project_staff_assignment  still not convincing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your edits, it seems that the count of days is every day beginning with the start day until the end day including start and end. This statement should do:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    datestart,
    dateend,
    -- because datediff won't include both, start and end, we'll add one day
    datediff(dateend, datestart) + 1 as daterange, 
    (datediff (dateend, datestart) + 1) * `hours` as total_hours
FROM 
    project_staff_assignment
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50df7e/3)**